# How to convert this list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list currently that looks like this

```
list =  [['hate', '10'], ['would', '5'], ['hello', '10'], ['pigeon', '1'], ['adore', '10']]
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary like this

```
dict = {'hate': '10', 'would': '5', 'hello': '10', 'pigeon': '1', 'adore': '10'}
```

So basically the `list [i][0]` will be the key and the `list [i][1]` will be values. Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: I take it you mean, for example, `{'hate': '10'}` instead of `['hate': '10']`?

Comment: Yes, haha, sorry about that mistake

Comment: Also, do you want a list of dictionaries or a single dictionary?

Comment: Basically the point of doing this is that each key will hold a value. Then I will search through a .txt file that contains a long paragraph of words for these keys. If found, then a counter will add the corresponding value of the key to a sum. And then in the end I have to present the sum. I don't know if that helps answer the question :(. Sorry I am quite new at this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `dict` constructor:

```
In [1]: lst =  [['hate', '10'], ['would', '5'], ['hello', '10'], ['pigeon', '1'], ['adore', '10']]

In [2]: dict(lst)
Out[2]: {'adore': '10', 'hate': '10', 'hello': '10', 'pigeon': '1', 'would': '5'}
```

Note that from your edit it seems you need the values to be integers rather than strings (e.g. `'10'`), in which case you can cast the second item of each inner list into an `int` before passing them to `dict`:

```
In [3]: dict([(e[0], int(e[1])) for e in lst])
Out[3]: {'adore': 10, 'hate': 10, 'hello': 10, 'pigeon': 1, 'would': 5}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was incredibly helpful

Comment: Hi again, I do have a part 2 to this question

So now that I have the dictionary, I would like to search through a text file for the keys. How would I create a loop to search the text for these keys?

Comment: Hi John - this really deserves a separate question on SO: do a search first to find if it's been answered before because there are several Python tools that might help.

Comment: HI xnx, thank you so much. I have asked the question separately:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826229/how-to-search-for-the-dictionary-keys-in-a-list

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(list)
for i in xrange(len(list)):
    dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1]
```

Gives:

```
>>> dict
{'pigeon': '1', 'hate': '10', 'hello': '10', 'would': '5', 'adore': '10'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list =  [['hate', '10'], ['would', '5'], ['hello', '10'], ['pigeon', '1'], ['adore', '10']]

new_dict = dict(list)
```

**Out put:**

```
{'pigeon': '1', 'hate': '10', 'hello': '10', 'would': '5', 'adore': '10'}
```