# How to search for the dictionary keys in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, search, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary of:

```
lst = {'adore': 10, 'hate': 10, 'hello': 10, 'pigeon': 1, 'would': 5, 'elections': 5}
```

And I have a list of:

```
mylist = [['a new', 'party'], ['to', 'lol'], ['compete'], ['in', 'adore', 'the 2013'], ['federal', 'elections'], ['The Free', 'Voters'], ['leadership', 'declined to'], ['join forces', 'according to', 'a leaked'], ['email from', 'Bernd Lucke'], ['Advocating', 'adore'] ]
```

I want to be able to search the list for the keys in the dictionary. If a word in the list is a key, then to take the value of that key and add it to a counter. In the end, to have a total sum of all the values.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `mylist = ['a', 'new', 'party', 'to', 'compete', 'in', 'the', '2013', 'federal', 'elections.',...]`? Or `mylist = [['a new', 'party'], ['to', 'lol'],...]`?

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion, I've made some changes for it to make more sense

Comment: Ah, thanks for edit :D

Comment: Now, please check if my answer is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
lst = {'adore': 10, 'hate': 10, 'hello': 10, 'pigeon': 1, 'would': 5, 'elections': 5}
mylist = [['a new', 'party'], ['to', 'lol'], ['compete'], ['in', 'adore', 'the 2013'], ['federal', 'elections'], ['The Free', 'Voters'], ['leadership', 'declined to'], ['join forces', 'according to', 'a leaked'], ['email from', 'Bernd Lucke'], ['Advocating', 'adore']]

print([lst.get(i) for j in mylist for i in j if lst.get(i) != None])
print(sum([lst.get(i) for j in mylist for i in j if lst.get(i) != None]))
```

Output:

```
[10, 5, 10]
25
```

---

If you don't like them in one line:

```
total = []

for i in mylist:
    for j in i:
        if lst.get(i) != None:
            total.append(lst.get(i))

print(sum(total))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with if statements?

Comment: @JohnGringus: Edited, is this you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do this in a more pythonic way.

```
lst = {'adore': 10, 'hate': 10, 'hello': 10, 'pigeon': 1, 'would': 5}
counter = {'adore': 0, 'hate': 0, 'hello': 0, 'pigeon': 0, 'would': 0}
mylist = [['a new', 'party'], ['to', 'lol'], ['compete'], ['in', 'adore', 'the 2013'], ['federal', 'elections'], ['The Free', 'Voters'], ['leadership', 'declined to'], ['join forces', 'according to', 'a leaked'], ['email from', 'Bernd Lucke'], ['Advocating', 'adore'] ]

def func():
    for key in lst.keys():
        for item in mylist:
            if key in item:
                counter[key] = counter[key] + lst[key]

func()
print sum(counter.values())
```

Comment: How would I be able to add the value assigned to the key everytime it finds the key in the list instead of just adding 1?

Comment: Not what I'd call "pythonic" :-/

Comment: Edited, If I understand well what you need, you can use a temporary dictionary for store the number of occurrences and then take all the values of this dictionary and sum them fro the total.    
@brunodesthuilliers Sorry, I'm no expert.